# Using MD5 in F#

Tags: hash, f#, md5

I am currently trying to pick up F#. This is my first time using a .NET language, and consequently I am very unfamiliar with the available APIs.

As a beginner's project, I would like to implement my own duplicate file finder. I have been advised to use checksums, since the files I am comparing are quite large in size (mostly between 1MB and 10MB).

So far, this is what I have done: After checking the file lengths, I compare files with identical file lengths by reading all their bytes into byte arrays. Now I would like to use MD5 to compute the hash value of each byte array, and then delete duplicate files that share the same hash value.

I have some questions:

1. Is MD5 an appropriate tool for this task?
2. If not, what algorithm should I use instead?

Thank you for your help. I might post follow-up questions to your replies.

EDIT:

```
let readAllBytesMD5 (tupleOfFileLengthsAndFiles) =
    let md5 = MD5.Create()
    tupleOfFileLengthsAndFiles
    |> snd
    |> Seq.map (fun eachFile -> (File.ReadAllBytes eachFile, eachFile))
    |> Seq.groupBy fst
    |> Seq.map (fun (byteArray, eachFile) -> (md5.ComputeHash(byteArray), eachFile))
```

I would like to extract keys (hashed byte arrays) that have multiple values (corresponding files), and delete duplicate files. How may I improve and continue from the code sample above? I am not familiar with how MD5 works, and so I am stuck here. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: MD5 is insecure... Try using `SHA256`

Comment: Or better yet `HMAC SHA512`

Comment: For a toy project, really?

Comment: Thank you both. I am going to edit my post to include a code sample (in which I used MD5 -- haven't changed it for now). Will you kindly look through it and advise me on how I may improve and continue? I would like to extract keys (hashed byte arrays) that have multiple values (corresponding files), and delete duplicate files. Thank you.

Comment: md5 is fine for this application, security is not a concern here

Comment: If you compare number of bytes + MD5 that should be fine for all practical purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing specifically wrong with using MD5 for this task. However, MD5 is no longer considered to be a "strong" hash; it is relatively straightforward for determined parties to create files with different content but that have the same MD5 hash.

A more robust alternative, and the one I'll recommend is that you use one of the SHA-2 hashes like SHA256.

However, a performance note: hashing is only going to improve the performance of your tool if you cache the hashes of the files (and update the cache incrementally as files are added/deleted/modified). If you don't cache the hashes, you need to read the entire contents of both files *and* calculate their hashes each time you find a collision; if this tool is only going to be used for casual de-duplication, it may be faster/simpler to compare the contents of the files whenever you find files of the same size.

EDIT: Here's some sample code you can use. It'll detect duplicates but you'll need to write another function which determines how to resolve the collisions (for example, you may want to keep whichever file was created earliest).

```
open System.IO
open System.Security.Cryptography

/// Given a sequence of filenames, looks for duplicate files by comparing file lengths
/// and, if necessary, hash values calculated using the specified hash algorithm.
/// Returns a sequence of tuples; the first item in the tuple is a hash value and the
/// second item is a sequence containing the names of two or more files which have
/// the same length and hash value.
let findDuplicateFiles (algorithm : HashAlgorithm) (filenames : seq<string>) =
    filenames
    |> Seq.groupBy (fun filename ->
        (FileInfo filename).Length)
    |> Seq.collect (fun (_, sameLengthFilenames) ->
        // If there's only one file with this length, there's no duplication so don't return it.
        if Seq.length sameLengthFilenames = 1 then Seq.empty
        else
            // Possible duplication. Resolve by hashing the files and comparing the hashes.
            sameLengthFilenames
            |> Seq.groupBy (fun filename ->
                using (File.OpenRead filename) algorithm.ComputeHash)
            // Check for multiple files with the same hash value.
            // Return any such filenames so outside code can determine how to handle them.
            |> Seq.filter (fun (_, sameLengthFilenames) ->
                // Collision when two or more files have the same hash.
                Seq.length sameLengthFilenames > 2))

/// Given a sequence of filenames, looks for duplicate files by comparing file lengths
/// and, if necessary, hash values calculated using the SHA256 algorithm.
/// Returns a sequence of tuples; the first item in the tuple is a hash value and the
/// second item is a sequence containing the names of two or more files which have
/// the same length and hash value.
let findDuplicateFilesSHA256 filenames =
    // NOTE: The algorithm should be bound with 'use' or 'using' here so it can be disposed,
    //       but the F# 3.1 compiler appears to dispose the object too early.
    findDuplicateFiles (SHA256.Create()) filenames

//
let printDuplicateEntry (hash : byte[], filenames : seq<string>) =
    stdout.WriteLine ""
    stdout.Write "Hash: "
    stdout.WriteLine (System.BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", ""))
    for filename in filenames do
        printfn "    %s (Length: %i)" filename ((FileInfo filename).Length)

//
let findDuplicateFilesInDirectory path =
    Directory.EnumerateFiles (path)
    |> findDuplicateFilesSHA256
    |> Seq.iter printDuplicateEntry
;;

// Example usage:
findDuplicateFilesInDirectory @"C:\Users\Jack\Desktop";;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Would you mind providing me with some pseudocode so that I can have something to work with? I am new to programming and I am extremely unfamiliar with concepts like hashing and caching. Thank you.

Comment: I've added some example code. It actually does the thing I said not to do (calculate the hashes each time around) but I've tested it and the performance isn't too bad so you may not need to push it any further (e.g., caching the filenames/hash values).